# dynamic predicate in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Selecting multiple **transportation** groups based on another **parent @refID** thru predicate matching.
Example:

```
<parent refid="masterbill"/>
<transportation refid="housebill">
</transportation>
<transportation refid="transportUnit">
</transportation>
<transportation refid="masterbill">
</transportation>
```

My logic is to get GET ALL **transporation** is satisfied thru the condition below

```
IF @refID=="masterbill" 
else IF @refID=="trasportUnit" 
get only <transportation @refid="transportUnit">.
```

I tried doing it like below but I'm having an error on "*" part.

```
<xsl:if test="@refID=="masterbill">
<xsl:variable name='match' select="'*'"/>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="@refID=="transportUnit">
<xsl:variable name='match' select="'transportUnit'"/>
</xsl:if>
<for-each select="transportation[@refID=$match]">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<xsl:variable name='match'>
  <xsl:if test="@refID=="masterbill">*</xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="@refID=="transportUnit">transportUnit</xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="transportation[$match='*' or @refID=$match]">
```